# How to assign an event to a checkbox in datagrid view in C#?

Tags: c#

I want that when I check the checkbox in the datagrid view my button that is disabled at the beginning will be activated after I want the selected lines to be inserted in a table.

Comment: If you are in such a hurry you should give **all** informations to speed up response. Are you working with WPF? Then add the *wpf* tag

Comment: The following post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843488/datagridview-checkbox-event

Comment: from where you are populating data for your grid ???

Comment: From the database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if you are using the standard DataGridView from .NET but I will assume you do. Also the assumption goes that your checkbox is not binded to a model. 
Subscribe to the dataGridView_CellClick event and handle you case and handle there the business.

```
private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0/*myColumn*/ && e.RowIndex == 0 /*myRow*/)
        {
            myButton.Enable = true;
            //do other business
        } 

    }
```

Also the dataGridView_CellContentClick event can be used depending on what you need.

Comment: yes. Your column in which you hold the checkbox control. Maybe the dataGridView_CellContentClick is more suitable for your case. The CellClick event will be fired even if the use will not click in the checkbox but  the click is in the cell.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience I want the user to just select a line in the datagridview

Comment: Your description says otherwise "I want that when I check the checkbox in the datagrid view my button that is disabled at the beginning will be activated ". Plus you can use the dataGridView.SelectedRows to get the collection of selected rows.

Comment: En tous cas merci :)

Comment: I still don't understand why you downvoted my answer. :)

Comment: No I have not voted I'm debuting in this site I know not voted