# Incorrect value using LINQ on DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, linq

In my DataGridView, my first column is a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn; I need to check if there are any rows in the DataGridView where the first column is checked. To do this, I have the following code:

```
DataGridView_Camera_Selection.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow).Any(Function(row) row.Cells(0).Value.Equals(True))
```

This is called in many different events, two separate TextBox controls' Validating and TextChanged events as well as the DataGridView's RowsAdded, RowsRemoved, and CellContentClick events.

When the event is triggered from the DataGridView, the correct True or False value is returned from the Any query. However, when the event is triggered from either of the two TextBox controls, it always returns a False value from the Any query. This occurs regardless of if I have all of the controls bound to the same event via multiple Handles clauses or if I have each control event bound to its own event via one Hanldes clause per control event.

Why is it that the returned result would be correct when the underlining control (in this case, my DataGridView) invokes the code in event, but an incorrect result would be returned when something else invoke the code event?

Comment: Have you tried this in a new project? It appears to work for me (tested with both a `Button` and in a `TextBox`'s `TextChanged` and `Validating` events). Make sure that nothing is changing the check boxes' state right before you are about to run this code.

Comment: While this did not solve my issue, it did bring me to the solution that I needed. Due to the reasons found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843488/datagridview-checkbox-event, I needed to first commit the edit of the CheckBoxColumn.

Comment: Wait... It did _**not**_ solve your issue but it was the solution you needed? What??

Comment: No, your suggestion did not solve my issue. However, after doing some more searching as a result of your response I came to that SO question that did provide me with the solution.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought you were referring to the SO question all the time, that is, even when you said that "this did not solve my issue" ;). -- Glad you found a solution! You should close your question as a duplicate of the one in your link (or at least write an answer to this with your new code and mark it as accepted).