# How to check if a specific column in DataGrid is changed?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

As seen in the image provided below, I have a column named "DQ". I have a function called "Rerank" which updates the "Place" column, and I want it to run only if the checkbox in that specific column has been modified. How can this be done?

[image: Reference Image]

So, ultimately, I would assume it would <s>be a click event</s> check for a cell in that column to finish being edited looking something like:

```
if (column[7].clicked)
    Rerank()
```

or something like:

```
if (column[7].finshedEditing)
    Rerank()
```

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: Can you provide the Function `Rerank()` for us to see what you really wanted to do? It's unclear and limited information given by yours. Thanks

Comment: I just added some more information now, but really what it comes down to is that I want to do *something* when that column is finished editing. After looking into it a bit more, I believe I need to focus on looking into when a call in that column is finished being edited.

Comment: it depends.  we can't tell how the data populated into the grid (eg data bound) are you using mvvm ?  It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think what you are looking for is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843488/how-to-detect-datagridview-checkbox-event-change