# How to control the order of selected items from DataGridView using check-boxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

**Goal**

Currently looking to find a way how to select items from DataGridView and order it by the selected first at top.

**Example**

First selection by user:

```
Selected  Column1 Column2
             a       1
             b       2
             c       3
   x         d       4
```

Second selection...

```
Selected  Column1 Column2
             a       1
   x         b       2
             c       3
   x         d       4
```

Third selection...

```
Selected  Column1 Column2
   x          a      1
   x          b      2
              c      3
   x          d      4
```

**Order**

```
4th row 
2nd row
1st row
```

**Summary**

The 1st item selected by user was the 4th row, then the 2nd and lastly the 1st row.

**Question**

How can I get a list of the all rows in order as explained above?

**Current Code**

I created a checkbox column like so, so the user can see what they have selected.

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkBoxColumn.Name = "Selected";
checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Selected";
checkBoxColumn.ReadOnly = false;
productsView.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);
```

User then checks the checkbox to mark the selected records they desire, then they click a button to which opens another form.

But the order is mixed.

```
private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (var row in checkedRows)
    {
        DateTime dateTime = dateText.Value;
        string orderNumber = orderNumberText.Text;
    
        SelectedProducts form = new SelectedProducts(dateTime, orderNumber);
        form.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think i would:

1. Create a new list that would store my data depending on the new order.

   ```
   List<Item> SelectedItemList= new List<Item>
   ```
2. Listen to the checkbox column value change. Add to the "SelectedList" when checkbox is checked or remove it when
   unchecked.( [How to detect DataGridView CheckBox event change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843488/how-to-detect-datagridview-checkbox-event-change))

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
       dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
   }

   private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
       if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
       {
           if ((bool)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value) //the index of checkbox column
              SelectedItemList.Add(itemBindingSource.current as Item)//add data to the list
           else
              SelectedItemList.Remove(itemBindingSource.current as Item) // remove data to list
       }

   }
   ```
3. Then use the list as parameter to the form display.

   ```
   SelectedProducts form = new SelectedProducts(SelectedItemList);
   form.ShowDialog();
   ```

Comment: Just reading through all this, all makes sense until got to the point of `itemBindingSource.current as Item` Is this a valid code?

Comment: You don't need such a workaround, just order the selected rows based on their index.

Comment: @LV98 `itemBindingSource.current as Item` is just a way of getting the current selected row and adding/removing it from the `SelectedItemList`.

The concept is that you get the current selected row and add/remove it to the `SelectedItemList` (or array if you prefer).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to track the selection by each check-change. Just get the checked rows when you need them:

```
var checkedRows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => (bool)r.Cells["Selected"].Value == true)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: In general you should not have any dependency to the order of the selection, anyways, above code will do the trick for you,

Comment: That simple aha! :D Just did so much alterations.

Comment: The suggestion in the other answer will work, but you really don't need such a workaround :)

Comment: I changed it a bit as I figured out you are not relying on SelctedRows, instead you have your own checkbox column. You even don't need order-by. Just stop tracking selection, instead, get the checked rows when you need.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Good job there's people like to who can make life easier with lesser coding :D

Comment: No problem at all :)

Comment: How would I then get the values for any column?

Comment: The result of the query is a `List<DataGridViewRow>` and for each row, you can use its `Cells` property. You also have the option of projecting the result, before calling `ToList`, for example:  `.Select(r=>(THE COLUMN TYPE)r.Cells["THE COLUMN NAME"].Value)`.

Comment: What's the data source of your DataGridView?

Comment: It's a `DS.Tables[0]`. Using SQL Query into a `DataSet`. Nothing fancy, no dapper.

Comment: What's the data source of your DataGridView? You may find [`DataBoundItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) property of the row useful. If the data source is `DataTable`, `DataBound` contains instance of the `DataRowView` behind the row. You may project to `r=>(DataRowView)r.DataBoundItem`  in result, or project it to something more useful like `r=> new {X = ((DataRowView)r.DataBoundItem).Field<int>("X"), Y = ((DataRowView)r.DataBoundItem).Field<string>("Y")}`

Comment: If it looks confusing, just ignore for now :)

Comment: Yes a little aha! I'll take a deeper look into it. I am currently looking into how to filter via `textchanged`, but the checkboxes lose values..

Comment: That's obvious. The checkbox column that you created is an unbound column and doesn't have a backing field in `DataTable`, it's just a column in DataGridView. If you need to keep the checked status, you need to have it in your data table and create a bound column.

Comment: I've sorted that, using dapper. Thanks for the tip !

Comment: Hi, I have unchecked the checkboxes.. and it still shows the previous items selected.

Comment: Well, it's hard to guess what may be the problem. Make sure you are using bound columns.

Comment: All fully working now. Just out of curiosity where did you learn to code?

Comment: At work and at home during during work projects and personal R&Ds - I've never read a whole book, but read many articles and book chapters with regards to the projects/topics that I was working on.

Comment: Have you got any recommendations ?