# Updating the value of a Checkbox column in datagridview in c# by code

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, updating

I am trying to update the value of a checkbox column in datagridview in c# by code but it is not working. Here it is the code:

```
public frmShowData()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dgvAlumnos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvAlumnos.ReadOnly = false;
    updateAttendance();
}
public void updateAttendace(){
    foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvAlumnos.Rows)
    {
        if (attendance[r.Index] == true)
        {
            r.Cells[2].Value = true;
        }
        else
        {
            r.Cells[2].Value = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Attendance is the array of booleans where I have the values.

The column number 2 of the datagridview is the checkbox column.

However, the changes are not visible in the datagriview.
**I am using this code inside the form construct**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the underlying source of the datagrid? you typically have to change the source, then the datagrid should update itself

Comment: btw, `if` statements like these can be simplified -> you do not need an if to begin with:
`r.Cells[2].Value = attendance[r.Index];`

Comment: [How to detect DataGridView CheckBox event change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843488/how-to-detect-datagridview-checkbox-event-change)

Comment: I suggest you copy/paste the actual code as opposed to re-typing the code to avoid typing errors. For starters, In the form’s constructor, the method `updateAttendance();` will not be found because the method below is spelled differently.

Comment: In addition, the code in the constructor is a little confusing. Is what is missing is “where” in the constructor is the grid filled with data? From the posted code, on the last line of the constructor, when the code calls the `updateAttendance()` method… the `foreach` loop will never be entered since the grid has no rows. Unless there is something you are not showing, it makes sense that nothing is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using value = true instead.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dgvAlumnos.Rows)
{
    if (attendance[r.Index] == true)
    {
        r.Cells[2].Value = true;
    }
    else
    {
        r.Cells[2].Value = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Value insted of Selected, but the datagridview does not show the update. Do I have to put this code inside an event?

Answer (score 0):

Try these two after changing data

```
dgvAlumnos.RefreshEdit();
dgvAlumnos.Refresh();
```